# If $M$ has Jordan-Measure 0, then $M\times [a,b]$ has Jordan-Measure zero?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory

I saw a proof Where, if $M\subset\mathbb{R}$ has Jordan-Measure zero, then $M\times [0,1]$ Has Jordan-Measure zero too. But, it just happens with this interval or can be generalized for any closed (or even open) interval?

Comment: Yes, it can be generalized, at least to Fubini's theorem. Which specific case do you need?

Comment: Have you tried going through the proof, replacing $[0,1]$ with an arbitrary interval, seeing whether you can make changes so the modified proof works, Eduardo?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'll try it. But I just wanted to know if there is something stronger with less hypothesis or more general.  I just was a little curious about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea would be this: since $M$ has zero measure in the sense of Jordan, for whatever $\varepsilon > 0$ may be, it is possible to find finitely many intervals $\mathrm{I}_k$ whose lengths sum less than $\dfrac{\varepsilon}{b - a}$ then $\mathrm{I}_k \times [a, b]$ are finitely many rectangles covering $M \times [a, b]$ whose areas sum less than $\varepsilon.$ Q.E.D.